# Git Clone does nothing

Tags: git

On a new Windows VM, which sits behind a proxy. running git clone https://[company]@dev.azure.com/[company]/[project]/_git/[project] does absolutely nothing, as far as I can tell. It says "Cloning into [projectname]" but then finishes without error and doesn't create the folder.

I've also tried with the git gui tool and it fails also, saying see console for detail, but the console is blank.

I have also tried cloning public repos and get the same behaviour

Comment: have you tried running: 


`git clone https://[company]@dev.azure.com/[company]/[project]/_git/[project] [project]` ?

Comment: I have, no luck :(

Comment: It sounds like the proxy may be filtering a port, but filtering port 443 seems odd. Perhaps try to dump network traffic with Wireshark to diagnose what's happening?

Comment: Is the directory made then removed? Has the project already been initialized? Authentication has already been setup? Azure DevOps is a bit different from most other platforms. Have you ensured you followed all these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/code-with-git?view=azure-devops#install-git-command-line-tools?

Comment: Try `strace git clone ....`. It may print some useful info.

Comment: @ElpieKay, running windows unfortunately strace doesn't work :(

Comment: @treedust Yes! The folder is created and then deleted quickly

Comment: @DylanB are you positive that authentication is passing? As mttpgn has pointed out it is often easier to clone using ssh for azure devops. Are you passing the azure credentials when cloning. Typically a window will pop up asking for you to sign in.

Comment: @jhpratt this is an azure devops git issue, not a git issue.

Comment: @treedust I'm not ruling out it's an AzureDevOps problem, but I also can't clone anything from GitHub

Comment: @DylanB that changes the line of questioning then....

I'd check out Damian comment.

Comment: @Damian That link did solve the git issue. My azure devops build still fails because it can't pull from git, but I'm sure that's a different issue. git clone now works.

Comment: @DylanB happy it works now for you!!

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your company's set up, an SSH public key might be required to clone the repo. Make sure you have [generated a public/private keypair](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen#generating) and try to clone again replacing `https://` with `ssh://`.